# How to import text and number value data at the same time using importxml to a google spreadsheet

Tags: xml, google-sheets

My import data is only being parsed as text, instead of text and number values, when I attempt to use a function command eg =sum(J5-I5), error message "+VALUE" is displayed, with the underlying message "Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '$2.0396'is a text and cannot be coerced to a number". I tried changing the text to number, or number value but this does not work.

What I want to have imported is to have columns B-D & G-H in text, and columns E-F as number values. So I can Check Entry Price daily for increase/decrease, and Net% (Columns J-L).

I have the following code in A1 =http://www.colonialfirststate.com.au/Price_performance/performanceNPrice.aspx?menutabtype=performance&CompanyCode=001&Public=1&MainGroup=RF&BrandName=FC&ProductIDs=51&Product=FirstChoice+Wholesale+Pension&ACCodes=&ACText=&SearchType=UnitPrice&Multi=False&Hedge=False&IvstType=Retirement+products&IvstGroup=&APIR=&FundIDs=&FundName=&FundNames=&SearchProdIDs=&Redirect=1.

And use the following in B4 =importhtml(A1, "TABLE",10). Refer screen capture below.

(1) Is it possible to import both text and number values using importxml, or do you have to do two seperate imports, if the latter how do you request data to be imported as a number value.
(2) How to have data automatically updated.

[Importxml url[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8rC3.png)

Comment: Where are you importing this data? It looks like a spreadsheet program, can you [edit] the question to include the program and how the steps are you do to import the XML file? Also what is the URL to the XML file or can you paste the XML file to the question (if it isn't big enough).

Comment: Hi Progman, Have you got an answer for the above query ?

Comment: You still have to provide the XML file or the URL to the XML file you are trying to import to your question. Since you are using google spreadsheet, please provide the steps how you have imported the XML file.

Comment: Progman here is the url: http://www.colonialfirststate.com.au/Price_performance/performanceNPrice.aspx?menutabtype=performance&CompanyCode=001&Public=1&MainGroup=RF&BrandName=FC&ProductIDs=51&Product=FirstChoice+Wholesale+Pension&ACCodes=&ACText=&SearchType=UnitPrice&Multi=False&Hedge=False&IvstType=Retirement+products&IvstGroup=&APIR=&FundIDs=&FundName=&FundNames=&SearchProdIDs=&Redirect=1. This is placed in cell A1 in the google spreadsheet, and =importhtml(A1, "TABLE",10) is entered in cell B4, which imports the table. Google fixed the formatting problem. So this issue can now be closed.